# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'

Tags: python, pandas

Для расчета статистических параметров хочу использовать pandas_profiling.
Работаю в google.colab.

[image: Уставливаю pandas_profiling]

Ошибка при вызове:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)`

Comment: Спасибо, так пробовала, но тоже была ошибка

Answer (score 1):

помогла установка отсюда:

!pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip